# glassfish4 create-node-ssh failed due to ssh key exchange not finished

Tags: ssh, glassfish

I'm trying to create a node on a remote host(I've already created a domain).

I'm running the command:
`asadmin -p <port_number> create-node-ssh --nodehost <remote_hostname> --installdir <glassfish_installed_dir_path> <node_name>`

and getting the following error everytime:

```
remote failure: Warning: some parameters appear to be invalid.
SSH node not created. To force creation of the node with these parameters rerun the command using the --force option.
Could not connect to host <hostname> using SSH.
There was a problem while connecting to <hostname>:22
Key exchange was not finished, connection is closed.
Command create-node-ssh failed.
```

From the error it seems that there is some connection problem. But I can ssh to the target server and I'm using the same key_pair.

After searching for some solution ([link1](https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-13075), [link2](https://java.net/jira/si/jira.issueviews:issue-html/GLASSFISH-12679/GLASSFISH-12679.html)) I found that trying to login through `ssh` without password could solve this.
But no luck. Now I can `ssh` to & from the target server without password as well. But this issue is still there.

What should I check for, in order to resolve this ?
Let me know if I'm missing out anything.

Comment: My guess is that it may not be using the correct SSH **user** - so the key file is valid, but not for the user that GlassFish is trying to connect with. Your command there seems to be missing both `--sshuser` and `--sshkeyfile`. Without these, it will definitely not work.

Comment: according to [oracle_glassfish_ref_manual](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26576_01/doc.312/e24938/create-node-ssh.htm#GSRFM00048) if don't specify these options, it will take the default ones. The default `sshuser` is one running the DAS process(server where I'm running the command) & default `sshkeyfile` will be under `/.ssh` directory(I don't have any other keys).

Comment: I'm having the same issue now... how did you solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try to start sshd daemon in debug mode to a different port at the remote node host:

```
sudo sshd -D -d -e -p 23
```

and try create-node-ssh command against that ssh port?:

```
asadmin -p <port_number> create-node-ssh --nodehost <remote_hostname> --installdir <glassfish_installed_dir_path> --sshport 23 <node_name>
```

I had an issue regarding glassfish ssh exchange keys because of ssh newer versions deprecating older algorithms:

```
Unable to negotiate with X.X.X.X port XXXXX: no matching key exchange method found. Their offer: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 [preauth]
```

My solution was to add legacy keys to /etc/ssh/sshd_config:

```
KexAlgorithms +diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
Ciphers +aes128-cbc
```

Even if this is not your case, sshd debug will surelly give you more information.